# Understanding Selectall_hashref and fetching/printing more than 1 column

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a PERL script that is connecting to a MySQL database, and selecting all the data from a table limited by set criteria in the form:

```
my $hash_ref = $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql, 'Key');
```

When I later deference and print my hash I only get my Key column to print:

```
print "$_\n" for (sort(keys %$hash_ref));
```

What do I need to do to get other columns (of my choosing) of the SQL table to print? Do I need to assign more keys? Am I fundamentally not getting how hashes work?

If it makes a difference, the first $hash_ref is from one function, and then is returned to the main script, and reentered into a second function that prints it.

EDIT: Corrected code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `keys %$hash_ref`, of course you see only the keys!

You can print the entire hash like:

```
print "$_ -> $hash_ref->{$_}\n" for (sort(keys %$hash_ref));
```

If your hash is a hash of hashes, as suggested in your comment, you can print the `col1` key like:

```
print "$_ -> $hash_ref->{$_}->{col1}\n" for (sort(keys %$hash_ref));
```

For printing a debug dump of any variable, you might find `Data::Dumper` handy:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($hash_ref);
```

Comment: That's giving me "Key Column" -> HASH('Raw Hash'). Also, what if I only want to print a particular other column in the hash?

Comment: If you have a hash of hashes, you can use two `->{...}` to get one value.  Example added to answer.